# Is it possible to CNAME to a youtube profile?

Tags: domain-name, cname

Just wondering if there is a way to CNAME to a youtube profile? I've tried a CNAME to a subdomain that auto redirects to youtube, but that's not working (i know it's convoluted, unfortunately due to the way my friend has his domain/site set up it's a pain in the backside)

Is anyone able to offer some assistance on this? I'd seriously appreciate it :)

Andy

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but you could set a CNAME to YouTube.com but not to YouTube.com/user/name

Comment: A friend wants youtube.domain.com to go to his youtube profile, his site is set up on Squarespace and apparently there's no way of doing a sub domain to redirect to the profile. Might have to think of another way

Comment: YouTube.domain.com should be able to REDIRECT to a YouTube profile (technically that's possible, however I don't know what limitations squarespace imposes).  CNAME has nothing to do with that tho.

Comment: Yup, which is what I've already explained. CNAME is the only option i have for custom redirection, hence why the question is about it

Comment: And CNAME won't do that for you.   What CNAME will do is allow you to say YouTube.example.come uses the same IP address as YouTube.com, it does not allow you to specify a path on YouTube.

Comment: You can't set up a page with redirect instead? Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page

Comment: @Darius he wants youtube.domain.com, i know how to do redirects etc. Have tried pointing a CNAME to a directory on my own domain that 301 redirects to youtube but it doesn't like it. What you're suggesting and what others suggest work in "normal" conditions but I can't really do these ideas

Comment: I'm just gonna have to tell him the only way to do this is to purchase a subdomain from his domain provider, that in theory is the best plan